# Are there good reasons to go against the one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many database archetypes?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a table called **'product'** with the following columns: **id, name, price and tablename.**

I have a group of tables named after the column tablename of the table **'product'**, and with the following columns: **customer_id and quantity.**

I wanted to join the table **'products'** with the count of the rows for each associated tables.

If the tables were set up in a conventional way 2 tables called **'transaction'** and **'product'** in a one to many relationship, I could have done this:

```
SELECT product, count(*)
FROM product p
INNER JOIN transaction t on p.product_id = t.product_id
GROUP BY product
```

However, it's not set up this way, so I had to do this:

```
SELECT p.name, p.price, p.id, p.tablename, t.table_rows as Count
FROM products p
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT table_name, auto_increment
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES) t on t.table_name = p.tablename
```

which is not too bad. So is there a reason (an advantage) why using this unconventional database structure can be useful? We have some tables with 3000 transactions. I always thought the one-to-many archetypes should always be used. I don't want to ask my lead developer why he did it this way so as to not sound rude to him.

Comment: "I have a group of tables named ..." -- _Do not do that!_